# UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library not found

Tags: android, android-studio, wikitude, .so

I used the Wikitude SDK v4 and when i launch my Activity i get this error. My IDE is Android Studio 1.5 and targetSDK 22

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/xxxx/libarchitect.so" not found.
```

I have the *wikitudesdk.jar* in my *app/libs* folder and here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
...

}
```

Best reguards

Comment: What's inside unzipped apk file /lib directory? List all libs with all architectures

Comment: In my lib/ directory I have : *arm64-v8a/libarchitect.so* , *armeabi-v7a/libarchitect.so*, *x86/libarchitect.so* . That's all

Comment: And what's your device?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `System.load("data/data/yourpackagename/lib/soname.so")` (using the real path to your `.so` file).

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Directory separator should not appear in library name: data/data/

Answer (score 0):

try this in your build.gradle file

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libarchitect.so"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code above doesn't work.The same error :

`dlopen("/data/data/xxxx/libarchitect.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/xxxx/libarchitect.so" not found` `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/xxxx/libarchitect.so" not found`

Answer (score 0):

You actually use    targetSdkVersion 23. Try targetSdkVersion 22.
It may be the problem wit text relocations in .so for android 6.0

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3028

Answer (score -4):

I have same kind of error while using wikitude library. I Resolved it by reverting the project-level build.gradle classpath to

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

from

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

It also requires changing the Project level setting to use default gradle wrapper (<kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Build, Execution, Deployement</kbd> -> <kbd>Gradle</kbd>)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11403042)

Comment: I have same kind of error while using wikitude library; resolved it by changing the build.gradle(Project) to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'.

Comment: I have same kind of error while using wikitude library;Resolved it by changing the build.gradle(Project) classpath to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0' from 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'. Also change the Project level setting  to use default gradle wrapper(Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployement-> Gradle)