# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library ".so" needed or dlopened by ".so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"

Tags: java, android, dlopen, .so

I'm working on an Android Project and I need to add a (.jar) library `awesomework.jar` .

When I add the library and run the project in my Android device I receive the below error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libDecodeApi.so" needed or dlopened by "/system/lib64/anotherlib.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"
```

The program crash inside my `awesomework.jar` in line `System.loadLibrary("DecodeApi");`

My setup:

- Android OS Version: 10
- minSdkVersion: 18
- targetSdkVersion: 18

What I search for

1. [Reading this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60949833/3126736), I tried to set `main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']` in `build.gradle`. This doesn't work because when I pull off the `libDecodeApi.so` from android device, the error came again searching for another `.so` file in `/system/` directory like `libc++.so` and many others. So I understand that pulling off almost all necessary shared objects from `/system` directory is not the solution.
2. I found that all needed libraries are also under the `/vendor` directory. I' m not quite sure but due to my `targetSdkVersion` and my Android OS Version should my `awesomework.jar` search for those shared objects under `/verdor` directory which is valid(?) for my Android OS?
3. Is something that can I do outside the `awesomework.jar` and force my library to search in `/vendor` directory? I don't have access to `awesomework.jar` source files.
4. If I had access to `awesomework.jar` source files (searching in more academic level now), is it acceptable to add the full path to `System.loadLibrary();` in order to force it search in `/vendor` dir? Something like that `System.loadLibrary("vendor/lib64/DecodeApi");`. [I saw this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113321/3126736) providing a path in project dir.

Any other thoughts, how to approach this problem and find a solution?